# How to get year from the dates and use it in angularjs chart

Tags: angularjs, fusioncharts, angular-chart

Hi Im working on angularjs charts. Here the data for the chart rendered are in the `date format ("dd-mm-yyyy")`, from the `date` I have to get the `year` and display it in the chart. But I'm not sure,how to get, only the `year` from the data provided. In the chart image x-axis represents the shares for specific year and y-axis represent the  percentage . In the image posted,you can see a red box along the y-axis which displays the full `date`, instead I want to display only the year in the y-axis. Please help me.

html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title> 
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-charts/0.2.7/angular-charts.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.js"></script>
  </title>
  <body>
  <div ng-app="chartApp" ng-controller="chartController">
    <canvas width="600" height="400" type="column2d" dataformat="json"
               dataSource="{{myDataSource}}"></canvas>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Controller:

```
var chartApp =angular.module("chartApp",["chart.js"]);
chartApp.controller("chartController",function($scope){

$scope.myDataSource = {
          chart:{ caption : "Share Check with previous years"},
          data :[{
                  label: "26/01/2010/", 
                  value: "80"},

                 {label : "26/01/2011" ,
                  value : "70"},

                 {label : "26/01/2012",
                  value : "52"},

                 {label : "26/01/2013",
                  value : "5"},

                 {label : "26/01/2014",
                  value : "33"},

                 {label : "26/01/2015",
                  value : "47"}]};
           });
```

[image: In the image x-axis represented in percentage and y-axis represent the year of sales]

Comment: can you please provide its fiddle

Comment: I have a fiddle but its not working

Comment: Ok but  I will be able to help you only once I will get fiddle, because this code is not working in my system.

Comment: ok shall I post my fiddle so you can make changes if needed

Comment: Yeah I will try to solve  :)

Comment: hi this the fiddle , `https://jsfiddle.net/329hus9s/ `

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y3H2G/2141/  this an edited chart this how my current chart looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just modify your `data` before assigning it to chart?

```
var data = [{
  "label": "20/11/2012",
  "value": "880000"
}];

angular.forEach(data, function(item) {
  item.label = item.label.split('/')[2];
});

$scope.myDataSource.data = data;
```

Answer (score 1):

FusionCharts do not allow manipulation with date and time values directly as of now.

Though for the scenario you described, it can be achieved by splitting the `data.label` *(date value)* to year values.

You can [check this JSFiddle with your data](http://jsfiddle.net/sikrigagan/j5akuetc/) for the same.